# code first with different entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have three model classes and three views. Models are given below

```
 public class BASLPApplicationFormModel
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int BASLPApplicationID { get; set; }


            public string BASLPApplicationNo { get; set; } 

            public string ApplicantName { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            [Display(Name = "Date of Birth", Prompt = "DD/MM/YYYY")]
            public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }        


            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Email-ID")]        
            public string EmailID { get; set; }

}
```

and second

```
  public class DPPHIApplicationFormModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int DPPHIApplicationID { get; set; }


        public string DPPHIapplicationNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name of Applicant")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Expansion of Initial")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string InitialExpansion { get; set; }


        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth", Prompt = "MM/DD/YYYY")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email-ID")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
```

and third

```
    public class DTYDHHApplicationFormModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int DTYDHHApplicationID { get; set; }    


        public string DTYDHHAapplicationNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name of Applicant")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string name { get; set; } 



        [RegularExpression("^([0-9]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "Land Line Number")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }    

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email-ID")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
```

Email model ,

```
[Table("Emails")]
    public class UserEmails
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string UserEmailID { get; set; }
    }
```

Here user interacts with any of the forms and submitting their forms accordingly.

I would like to get all Email entries to my Emails table using code first approach and please advice me how can  achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this serie of three blogposts:

1. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx
3. http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Hope this helps